# How to access JNDI DataSource with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, quartz-scheduler, jndi

According to this documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase#exposing-the-datasource-through-jndi

I simply need another entry in my `application.conf` to expose a DataSource in JNDI:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
```

I've added `"tyrex" % "tyrex" % "1.0.1"` to my `libraryDepenencies` in `build.sbt`.

From reading several other posts on this, it sound like I should be able to simply use

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) play.api.libs.JNDI.initialContext().lookup("DefaultDS");
```

To fetch the DataSource from JNDI. However, when I try this it throws the following Exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DefaultDS not found
    at tyrex.naming.MemoryContext.internalLookup(Unknown Source)
    at tyrex.naming.MemoryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

The main reason I'm trying to do this is so that Quartz can re-use the DataSource/ConnectionPool created by Play instead of defining another in quartz.properties. According to the docs:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html

I should need the following two lines in `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = h2
org.quartz.dataSource.h2.jndiURL = DefaultDS
```

However, Quartz throws a bunch of exceptions:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'DefaultDS' javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DefaultDS not found [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve datasource via JNDI url 'DefaultDS' javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DefaultDS not found]
```

I'm not sure where to go next. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I simply needed to add `jdbc` to my `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`. This created and exposed the DataSource in JNDI.